# iOS Save SecIdentityRef in keychain so it can be queried uniquely

Tags: ios

I am trying to save a SecIdentityRef in the keychain, so that it can be queried uniquely. My code looks like this

```
       NSMutableDictionary *keyAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
       [keyAttr setObject:label forKey:(__bridge NSString*)(kSecAttrLabel)];
      [keyAttr setObject:(id)self.identityRef forKey:(__bridge    NSString*)kSecValueRef];
        [keyAttr setObject:identityTag forKey:(__bridge NSString*)(kSecAttrApplicationTag)];
       [keyAttr setObject:(__bridge  NSString*)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly forKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecAttrAccessible];
        OSStatus secStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, nil);
```

I am setting the kSecAttrApplication Tag , so that when I query using SecItemCopyMatching , I get only a single match. However , when I try this code, the secStatus code is -25303 (Invalid argument), which is due to kSecAttrApplicationTag. 
Can I use kSecAttrApplicationTag to uniquely identify items? What is the best way to store identity with a unique search attribute?